How many isomorphism classes are there of strings of length $n$ over alphabet $\Sigma$ of size $k$?
Isomorphisms of Strings.
$$
s = aa \simeq bb\\
s = ab \simeq ba
$$
So the set of strings over a 2-letter alphabet of length 2 have merely 2 isomorphism classes.
$$
s = aaa \simeq bbb \\
s = aab \simeq bba \\
s = aba \simeq bab \\
s = baa \simeq abb \\
$$
There are a total of $2^3$ strings, so we've captured all of them, yet there are merely $4$ isomorphism classes.
Let's add in another letter $c$.  Let $\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$.  Then:
$$
s = aaa \simeq bbb \simeq ccc \\
s = aab \simeq aac \simeq bba \simeq bbc \simeq cca \simeq ccb\\
s = aba \simeq aca \simeq bab \simeq bcb \simeq cac \simeq cbc \\
s = abb \simeq acc \simeq baa \simeq bcc \simeq caa \simeq cbb \\
s = abc \simeq acb \simeq cab \simeq cba \simeq bca \simeq bac \\
$$
There are $3^3$ strings on 3-letters so we've captured them all, and there are a total of $5$ isomorphism classes!
Definition.  An isomorphism between two strings $s,t \in \Sigma^{n}$ is a permutation $\sigma : \Sigma \simeq \Sigma$ such that $\sigma(s) = t$, where we apply $\sigma$ to a string homomorphically.
Question. What is the exact number of isomorphism classes $[s] \in \Sigma^n/\simeq$ when $|\Sigma| = k$?
Attempt.
I think maybe we count all ways of putting $n$ unique balls into $|\Sigma|$ bins.  But this doesn't equal the example counts above.

This appears to be from first principles
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{\sum_{q=1}^k {n\brace q}.}$$
Note also as a sanity check that
$$\sum_{q=1}^k {n\brace q} {k\choose q} q!
= n! [z^n] \sum_{q=0}^k {k\choose q} \frac{1}{q!} (\exp(z)-1)^q q!
= n! [z^n] \exp(kz) = k^n.$$

https://oeis.org/A102661

Please, what is ${n \brace q}$?

@RobPratt How can that sequence match this one; how can you have a value of $1$ from larger and larger $n$?  In other words, how can the isomorphism classes just all go to one isomorphism class as $n$ increases (sometimes)?

The group $S_k$ acts on $X =\Sigma^{n} =$ the set of all $n$-length strings over $\Sigma$ where $|\Sigma| = k$.
Namely a symmetry $g \in S_k$ induces one on each string $s \in X$ where $s = \sigma_1\cdots \sigma_n$ for $\sigma_i \in \Sigma$ via $g\cdot s = \sigma_{g(1)} \cdots \sigma_{g(n)}$.
$$
\text{Orb}(s) = \{ t \in X: g\cdot s = t \text{ for some } g \in S_k\}
$$
Clearly the orbits partition the set $X$ and the $\text{Orb}(g)$, $g\in S_k$ are the same thing as the isomorphism classes we seek.
We have that by Burnside's lemma:
$$
|X/S_k| = \frac{1}{|S_k|} \sum_{g \in S_k} |X^g| = \sum_{x \in X}|\text{Stab}(x)|
$$
where $|X/S_k|$ is what we're aftter, and $X^{g} =$ the set of all elements of $x$ fixed by $g$ or $X^g = \{ x \in X : gx = x\}$.
How many automorphisms are there as $|\text{Stab}(x)| = \#\{ g \in S_k : gx = x\} = \text{Aut}(x) \leqslant S_k$?
There are exactly the size of $\text{Aut}(x) = \prod_{a \in \Sigma} S_{l_a}$ or iow $|\text{Aut}(x)| = \prod_{a \in \Sigma} l_a!$ where $l_a =$ the total number of $a$'s occuring in $x$.
Thus the number we're after is:
$$
\sum_{x \in X} \prod_{a \in \Sigma}\left(\text{how many a's occur in x}\right)!
$$
